# Is a multipart plain text / HTML email necessary anymore?

Tags: php

I am using the PHPmailer class to send emails through my PHP application. However, trying to convert all of my HTML emails to plain text on the fly is posing it's challenges.

This got me to wondering- how many of you still support plain text emails? Is sending multipart plain text/HTML emails worth the trouble?

What are the reasons to support plain text emails anymore?

EDIT: For those who think that plaintext emails is still a necessity, are there any PHP classes/functions you would recommend to strip the HTML off the email body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into a reason to continue doing this, spam filters give some serious weight to emails that are HTML only.